# He advised me to go there. He advised me going there

Tags: reported-speech

I am not getting these two sentences. Are they fit for the indirect speech?

> He advised me to go there.
>
> He advised me going there.

Is this sentence indirect speech or is it not?

Comment: Please explain what you think is true, and what  you want to know. Both sentences could be describing indirect speech.  Do you wish to know which is more common/"idiomatic"?

Comment: Yes, Brain.Someone said, "He advised me going there, isn't indirect sentence. So , I wanna know about it . Either it is indirect sentence or not?

Comment: It's indirect, but "he" would probably have "**suggested** me going there" rather than "**advised** me going there" (in AmE).  Still, one could "advise **caution**" (a noun), so likewise one should be able to "advise [{me/my} going there]"  (a noun phrase). It's not a question of indirect-speech construction, it's a matter of word choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use to-infinitive after advise in indirect speech. So it is preferable to say "He advised me to go there".

You don't use the structure advise + object + present particple. However, if you use " about" in front of the present participle, I think your sentence will be correct grammatically as follows:

He advised me about going there.